# How to read the value of ExtensionObject

Tags: python, opc-ua

I want to read the value of this node, which is of type ExtensionObject, the value I read was `b'\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff'`, UAexpert UAexpert reads is [image: Uaexpert] , why is this? I have looked up a lot of data and methods, but there is no progress.I use wireshark to look through the messages transmitted between the server and the client, and I can also see the value is[image: wireshark].This is my code:

```
from opcua import Client, ua
server_url = "opc.tcp://localhost:4840"
client1 = Client(server_url)
client1.connect()r
import time

try:
    #call StartTransfer method
    method_0 = client1.get_node("ns=1;s=StartTransfer")
    parent_obj_0 = "ns=1;s=OpcUaDaqProfile"
    obj_1 = client1.get_node(parent_obj_0)
    out_1 = obj_1.call_method(method_0)

    node_id = "ns=1;s=data/OpcUaServer/channels/1/0_VALUES"
    node = client1.get_node(node_id)
    data_value = node.get_value()
    print("Node Value:", data_value.Body)
finally:
    client1.disconnect()
```

If someone can help,thank you advance.

Comment: you need add a MRE

Comment: I'm new to opcua programming, can you elaborate, what does MRE mean? Can you be more specific，how should it be reflected in my code@leaf_yakitori

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have updated the code in my question and given a complete minimum example. The server I use is the OPC UA Server of Dewesoft.Please have a look. If not, I can continue to modify my code or provide more information. Thank you very much.@D.L@leaf_yakitori

Answer (score 0):

The DataType of the value is a custom, server specific data type ("ns=1;i=1"), which UaExpert cannot display since the server does not provide the DataTypeDescription for it. Therefore it only shows "Unknown ExtensionObject" and can show the encoded binary that was transferred.

Therefore, you won't be able to decode it in your application either.

Comment: UAexpert can display coded binaries, but I just get the```b'\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff'```, how should I modify the code to get coded binaries?If you have some advices,thank you in advance.@Jouni Aro

Comment: As mentionted in previously, there could be a bug in python opcua. And as the library is not supported anymore, switch to asyncua. If you have the issue in asyncua, open a bug report in the github repository of asyncua.